# Trying to build simple Microservice getting error " Cannot execute request on any known server"

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, microservices, netflix-eureka

I am new in microservices and spring I have created simple microservice with Eureka server as bellow
I have not installed anything special on the system. Please let me know what do I need to install?

```
package com.dwf.demo.registration;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "eureka-server");

        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServer.class, args);

    }

}
```

and

```
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false

server.port=1111

spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false
```

while stating this maven project getting error as (Limited part of the log is shown)

```
2020-03-18 23:56:23.453  WARN 13680 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the instance info replicator

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:829) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:121) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_211]

2020-03-18 23:56:29.280  INFO 13680 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2020-03-18 23:56:51.073  INFO 13680 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2020-03-18 23:56:51.073  INFO 13680 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2020-03-18 23:56:51.073  INFO 13680 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2020-03-18 23:56:51.073  INFO 13680 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2020-03-18 23:56:51.073  INFO 13680 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2020-03-18 23:56:51.073  INFO 13680 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2020-03-18 23:56:51.073  INFO 13680 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2020-03-18 23:56:53.086 ERROR 13680 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:529) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.sendHeartBeat(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:102) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_211]


2020-03-18 23:56:53.086  WARN 13680 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2020-03-18 23:56:53.086 ERROR 13680 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_UNKNOWN/BTP208103.iuser.iroot.adidom.com - was unable to send heartbeat!
```

and my POM looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.dwf</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProcessRuleGenerator</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ProcessRuleGenerator</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.dwf.demo.ProcessRuleGeneratorApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Finchley.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

any suggetions will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

From the info you have provided it seems you are using same microservice as eureka server as well as your rest controller. 
As per my knowledge, there should be 2 different microservices. One should be your eureka server and other should be your api (rest controller) and eureka client which will register to eureka server. 
Sequence to bring those microservices is , first you start the eureka server and then the other apis (eureka clients). Also you need to specify the eureka's uri in app properties of the other apis which need to register to eureka.
Eg: eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/